# Export files from meteor project

Tags: download, meteor, offline

I am developing a meteor project which requires a deck-offline function. 
The idea of deck-offline means you can download a group of files to local pc from server side. 
I found a similar js file which provide an solution for it, the url is https://github.com/piatra/kreator.js/blob/master/lib/kreator-download.js.
So I want to ask if there is some package or api can implement the download file function from server side.

Answer (score 0):

I have found great use for CollectionFS:
https://atmospherejs.com/package/collectionFS

How to install packages from atmosphere can be found here:
https://atmospherejs.com/docs/installing

Hope this suits your needs.

Comment: Hi, The collectionFS seems for upload function. Do you have example of export files from meteor project.

Comment: no, not only updloads, from the README.md:"CollectionFS is a smart package for Meteor that provides a complete file management solution including uploading, **downloading**, storage, synchronization, manipulation, and copying."

Comment: Hi, is there any example code for it? @Alexander Meesters

Comment: Here you can find some code full of examples, among it, the download code: https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-example-filemanager/blob/master/client/client.js